# MDLMesh strange buffer layout

Tags: metal

I was curious to see the vertex positions of an MDLMesh for a boxWithExtent and I have notices a strange behaviour. When I print out the positions and normals for the first 3 vertices you get the below values. What I find weird is that for the 1st vertex we get 2 0.0s at the end to fit the stride for sims_float4 but weirdly for every subsequent vertex this becomes 1.0 - 0.0. Anyone has any idea why metal does this instead of just filling the last two positions with 0.0s as the first vertex. Thank you 0.5 0.5 0.5 -1.0 -0.0 -0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.5 -0.5 -1.0 -0.0 -0.0 1.0 0.0 0.5 -0.5 0.5 -1.0 -0.0 -0.0 0.0 1.0

This behaviour goes away if I use a custom vertexDescriptor so I'm confused as what's going on here